# Do Invulnerability potions work?

Tags: candy-box

Do Invulnerability potions work? The wiki has comments saying that they don't, and I tried them myself, and they don't.

So is it a joke potion, like the Superman potion, as it just says "You won't *feel* pain". Emphasis mine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [wikia page for Invulnerability potion](http://candybox.wikia.com/wiki/Invulnerability_potion) has indeed comments stating that sometimes it won't work, and [this user advices](http://candybox.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:3561):

> If anyone complains about their Invincibility potion not working, WAIT
>   FOR IT! It will work eventually. And also, if eventually it doesn't
>   work, tell aniwey [the developer]. He'll fix the bug.

[Another user](http://candybox.wikia.com/wiki/Thread:3546) reports never having this problem:

> I've never had that problem before; all I can say is to play at the
>   official site (if you're not already there) so you know you're playing
>   the most up-to-date version.

While searching on the web for potential use, you can find several topics ([as this one](https://www.giantbomb.com/candy-box/3030-42571/forums/so-how-the-heck-do-you-beat-the-dragon-1435944/)) where people are effectively using Invulnerability potions, without any problem.